# Audio duration is longer when streaming .mp3 from S3 using Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-s3, mp3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an audio file that is 04:47:43 in length but when I stream the file from an S3 bucket (distributed by Cloudfront) the browser lists the duration at 04:49:05.

The original file has a constant bitrate of 32kbps.

What could be causing the difference in duration?

Comment: In a word... nothing... nothing about CloudFront or S3 comes to mind that should be able to cause this, as neither modifies or processes content in any way (except CloudFront gzip, which only operates on text-based objects with an appropriate Content-Type).  Do you see the same issue if you pull the file directly from S3?  Have you tried submitting a CloudFront invalidation request for the file?

Comment: Same issue when using the direct S3 link to the file.  I have not tried submitting a Cloudfront invalidation request but I will look into that next.  Thank you for the reply!

Comment: I did some further testing and here's something even more bizarre - the duration is only wrong in Firefox.. Chrome has it correct.   I triple checked the file and also noticed in Firefox that the audio ends at the correct time (04:47:43) then immediately jumps to 04:49:05 at the end.  Weird!

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1133234